# Can modify system files/folders via SSH, but not via SFTP

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, permissions, mount, sftp

## My problem

I want to *mount* or *access* my Linux server's filesystem from my MacBook Pro. Some of the reasons for this include:

- Sometimes I edit files text files, but I want to be able to use standard macOS shortcuts (navigate, backspace, and delete shortcuts for words, lines, and paragraphs) that have arcane shortcuts in nano or vim
- File management with a lot of files is just easier for me with a GUI, especially when I can do things like renaming files based on Regex expressions
- I am just faster and like the GUI more
- This would allow me to more easily manage and transfer files to and from external drives connected to my Linux machine without having to plug it physically into my MacBook Pro every time, and then put it back on my Linux machine.

## What I have tried

With that out of the way, I have been trying to mount the Linux filesystem on macOS with no success.

### SSH

So, normally I can SSH into my Linux machine since it's connected to my local network—all I do is `ssh user@192.168.0.x` where `x` depends on the number of the device in the network. I put in the password for `user` and I'm in.

After I SSH in, I can create and modify files and folder at will, both inside and outside my home folder located at `/home/user`. However, this is not the mounting solution I'm looking for—I'm trying to *avoid* using the command line.

### SFTP

However, when I use SFTP to access the Linux machine using `sftp user@192.168.0.x`, I am *unable to modify files and folders outside of my home directory*. This is rather strange to me because I am logging in as the same user, except via SFTP instead of SSH, but I'm being given a lower set of permissions to create and modify files.

The issue with this is that the program I use, ForkLift, can virtually mount filesystems through the SFTP protocol. However, because I'm unable to modify any files outside of my home folder, I'm very limited in what I can do after mounting the filesystem in ForkLift.

### Samba

macOS has built-in support for mounting filesystems through Samba. So I decided to install smb on my Linux machine, and sure enough I was finally able to mount several folders which I could see and control directly from the Finder. However, I am still unable to modify anything outside of my home directory even through Samba.

### SSHFS

As a last resort, I tried installing sshfs on my macOS mine. I figured since it had SSH in the name, it would let me modify just as if I had SSH'd into my machine, right?

Well although I was able to mount it using `sshfs user@192.168.0.x:/ ~/Desktop/mount/remote-server`, I *still* am unable to modify anything outside of my home directory! So this is also a dead end.

## My question

How do I mount my Linux machine's filesystem on my MacBook Pro so that I can edit and modify files, both inside and outside my home folder?

Comment: Since SFTP and SMB show similar behaviour, I'm leaning towards this being a permission issue. Can you do an `ls -l` for a file inside your home directory and outside it? It will help compare permissions and ownership.

Comment: And a general comment: exposing the complete filesystem of your Linux box is a security nightmare, which is why that is normally not done. When you say "I want to access files outside of home", do you really mean system files (like in `/etc`), or other files (like your external hard drives, or user files that happen to be in some other place than your home directory)? If the latter, the standard solution is to expose those places also as Samba filesystems.

Comment: @dirkt Thank you for the information. The reason I wanted to expose the whole filesystem is because sometimes I need to edit configuration files (take `/etc/samba/smb.conf`, for instance). I much prefer navigating to that file and opening it in Sublime Text rather than using nano and the terminal. However, more importantly I usually mount my external volumes like you mentioned to `/volumes`, and I would like to transfer files to and from there after mounting. However, I noticed that after mounting my volume, even if I do it in `~/mount`, even through Samba, I still don't have edit access...

Comment: I do recommend against editing anything in `/etc` in that way. You'll need to edit it rarely enough, and the inconvenience in editing is low compared to the security problems. If you want to compare with MacOS: Catalina even makes it impossible to edit certain system setting files **on the same computer**, even with administrator rights, never mind sharing them on the network. Sharing external drives through Samba (as long as they don't contain files owned by root) is an exercise in debugging the permissions settings on both sides.